# How to scale a wrapper div and its inner content?

Tags: html, css

I need to scale up a div which contains other nested divs

Using `zoom` property works fine:

https://jsfiddle.net/aq11qjro/1/

But I know as some issue on Firefox browser, so I would like to use instead CSS scale property

Using `transform: scale`:

https://jsfiddle.net/aq11qjro/

I cannot get the desired effect.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you mean you want the "a" and "b" boxes to be responsive to the parents width/height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increase the size to 250%, you should use `scale(2.5, 2.5)` instead of `scale(2, 2)`:

But more importantly. `transform: scale` scales the div and centers it in its original space. Because it is larger in size, it will be outside of the screen. You can add `transform-origin: top left;` to specify that the top left corner of the scaled element should be anchored to the top left corner of the original space.

Updated fiddle with correct scale and transform-origin: https://jsfiddle.net/aq11qjro/7/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to scale up (increase size) for example of 250%

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the origin to top left

```
transform-origin: top left;
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq11qjro/5/)

(edit: I linked the wrong fiddle: corrected)